# Why would 1/5 of earthlings prefer to live in orbit rather than on the surface?

Tags: society, economy, space-constructs

The Great Depression (2030 - 2050) wiped out 2/3 of humanity, buried nation states and forced survivors to take concepts like democracy, sustainability and the environment really seriously.

The survivors faced the worst consequences of climate change, learned citizenship values and even rewrote the Universal Declaration of Human Rights stating that human beings have the right to peace, that proselytism is prohibited and that everyone has the right to an environment free of pollution.

The population did not recover easily. Even generations later the idea of having many children seems foreign to most, over the next two centuries the population grows slowly from 2.8 billion to still less than 5 billion.

However, it is a remarkably happy period for them: nuclear fusion is already a reality and the abundance of clean energy creates many opportunities. Different types of catalysts invented at about the same time at different research centers make water electrolysis efficient, with hydrogen-powered vehicles everywhere. Carbon allotropes allow for new constructions, lighter, more resistant, cheaper and even with the bonus of the raw material used being the 1.8 e+14 kg of carbon present in the excess carbon dioxide in the atmosphere.

In fact, the success of using graphene, nanotubes and carbyne to build everything was so great that the concern was reversed! It was feared that it would withdraw too much.

Laws (and taboo, perhaps stronger than any law) prevented mining or any other activity that might create a new imbalance in the Earth's carbon cycle (as well as the cycles of nitrogen, water, phosphorus, etc.).

So in 2070 they decided to go back into space.

Not for a competition of countries.

Nor based on the ego of billionaires.

Inhabit other planets? Earth seemed a lot more spacious now with half the population it once was.

The concern for sustainability extended to space: rockets launched from the surface were a thing of the past, from the heroic era of space exploration (1957 - 2030). The elders spoke of [satellite constellations](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/%7Egbakos/satellites/), [rocket debris falling out of control](https://www.space.com/nasa-esa-space-chiefs-condemn-china-rocket-debris-crash), [methane tank explosions](https://everydayastronaut.com/rocket-pollution/), and other things that looked like an abomination.

The obvious choice was [Konstantin Tsiolkovski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstantin_Tsiolkovsky)'s concept. They would build a space elevator.

The material for this was already at hand. In fact, it was because they wanted so much more from it that they were going back to space. Carbyne wires.

It didn't take long for them to have a dispute: where to build the elevator? America? Africa? Indonesia? When Parliament was about to split so they decided on six elevators equidistant along the equator: Belem, Libreville, Maleh, Gebe, Phoenix and Darwin. To top it off, they approved the suggestion brought by Arthur Clarke almost 100 years earlier in [The Fountains of Paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fountains_of_Paradise) a gigantic orbital ring connecting the elevators.

With so many minds now turned to space it was not a surprise when the technology to alter the orbits of asteroids and comets was improved and put to use. From the elevators it was very cheap to launch probes to reach the outer solar system that take blocks of ice from trans-Neptunian orbits towards the inner solar system. The dream of terraforming Mars and Venus was within reach. Launching many of them on Mars to recover the light elements lost in eons became a university project. Bringing in large chunks of rock and ice with enough energy to speed up Venus's rotation now just required patience.

If previously people sought to detect asteroids close to Earth to prevent a collision, now they wanted to find them in order to disassemble them into their basic elements.

The base industry was all moved to the Arthur Clarke geostationary ring. This made it necessary to create comfortable dwellings for human beings. Several housing models had already been imagined, designed, tested. The [O'Neill Cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder) was the most promising, but was discarded because of the [Coriolis effect](https://room.eu.com/article/investigation-of-the-coriolis-effect-in-rotating-space-platforms): the difference in gravity between the feet and heads of the inhabitants was greater than desired.

The station model chosen is a colossus: 45 km in diameter, 5 km wide. 300 meter high domes, self-sufficient with gas and water cycles complete and a controlled biosphere. Capacity for 200,000 permanent residents, or support 1 million under emergency conditions. Earth's gravity is emulated with a rotation every 300 seconds, 2.84 TWH of installed capacity in solar panels. Industrial installations that benefit from less gravity are placed between the living space and the central axis of the station, where the connection of the station with the elevators and with the surface of the Earth is made.

[image]

The stations multiply, the controlled environment for the industry is a factor. The idea of turning such an station into a kind of resort, like a private island appeals to others. Certain groups driven by a different religion, ideology or philosophy express interest. The complete structure of the Clarke ring is capable of supporting almost 16,000 stations, the materials are almost all already in space and the Earth's surface is getting cleaner.

Some even more eccentric ones act criminally and disconnect the stations of the ring. They call themselves *Wanderers* and [love to paraphrase Carl Sagan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS3TSXekjLo), while earthlings call them pirates.

In 2117, human beings finally set foot on Mars and this made the planet a place of pilgrimage. Muslims visit the vallis marinellis, which they call the Prophet's Valley. Buddhists dream of a retreat on top of Olympus and Christians see on Mars - [red like jasper](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2021%3A11&version=NIV) - the Celestial Jerusalem promised since the times of John the Evangelist. A stationary ring is built around Mars and the Catholic Church provides 12 space elevators, the 12 gates of Celestial Jerusalem. In the name's dispute they decide to call them by the names of the apostles rather than the tribes of Israel, and sponsor mass immigration of Christians from Earth to Mars, for, as Pope Leo 14 stated in 2142: "*Jesus said that the His kingdomis not of this world, the Earth; so we must make another world the kingdom of Our Savior*". One billion people emigrate from Earth to Mars over the next 100 years.

Thus the Earth became increasingly uninhabited.

And even with all the motivations given: controlled industrial environment, ease of obtaining raw materials, isolated communities, wealthy resorts, this still seems insufficient motivation to have 16,000 space stations in space (or 20,000 if you count the Martian, lunar and wandering).

Sorry for the long winded, the question, finally:

**What else would motivate humans to inhabit these space stations? What socioeconomic force would attract them?**

In 2240, 10,893 stations are built and they estimate to build another 5,079 by 2300. 773 million people live in them. There are another 1 billion humans on Mars (surface and ring) and another 10~50 million in wandering stations (government agents on Ceres and Vesta plus mining companies on the asteroids, aside the pirates). **Why would about 1 in 5 earthlings prefer to live in these stations than on the Earth's surface and still motivate the construction of so many?**

==========

**Some details that answers and comments make it necessary to add:**

Slow population growth from a population that is only a fraction of that it once was makes the live standard on Earth high and enjoyable for all.

The Christian exodus to Mars begins (~2140) shortly after the construction of the first stations in Earth's orbit (~2112) and this already creates a depopulation problem on the planet. Out of every 9 people, 2 will move to Mars.

The industrial activity does employ a lot of people, but still proportionally less than today where they are 10 ~ 12% of the workforce, therefore, not all the manufacturing industry in orbit will be a reason for this.

Low-gravity activities are easy to have, there are low-gravity stop stations in space elevator sessions, and like any entertainment activity, it will share attention with dozens of others.

Fashion works both ways: there will be Earth people willing to live in bucolic stations with the bored same weather and no rain just as there will be station-born people preferring a more diverse life on the surface.

The enormous depopulation of the surface makes cities want to attract as many people as possible, in addition to wanting to retain. Even the pope's religious call to change of planet will be evaluated by millions of Christians in their pros and cons with offers of permanence in Recife, Boston, Lisbon, Chennai or Abidjan.

Yet with all that, the equivalent of the entire population of Europe, or half of China, would rather live in orbit than on the surface of planets. Why?

=========

Kinda offtopic, answer the comment:

In the expedition to Mars in 2117 Alhazred, Carlson, Jackson, Hamilton, Lösch and Xuesen explore a cave in Nectaris, in the middle of the canyons of the Vallis Marinellis and find signs in Arabic dating from about 1500 years before, as well as strange vitrified black rocks in Mars that resemble the Kaaba.

Investigations confirm authenticity (Alhazred and Jackson had nothing to do with it) and create a commotion: how or what would have done it? What else would there be to investigate and now it was submerged in the protooceans of Mars?

Legends about Muhammad are revised. The idea that the Prophet lay somewhere between Heaven and Earth took on new meaning. The inscription saying in classical Arabic "From here I departed" was incontrovertible proof that the [Al Aqsa mentioned in the Holy Quran](https://quran.com/17?startingVerse=1) was nowhere in Arabia, Jerusalem or elsewhere on Earth. It really was "the furthest".

This also brought up the old suggestion that the relief of the valleys somehow forced [the name of the Prophet inscribed on the Martian surface](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMH9i13fF7w&ab_channel=NaseerHomoud), something that the current coastline reinforced.

Thus, without delay, Islamic law jurists proclaimed that every Muslim who has already performed the Hajj to Mecca should, as far as possible, try to make the pilgrimage to Al Aqsa on Mars.

However, Muslims are discouraged from living on Mars. Martian children will never be able to set foot on Earth and this prevents the main pilgrimage to Mecca.

Comment: Well written!  It unfolds like the story it is.

Comment: Given how complex and unpredictable human preferences are I suspect that there will be myriads of reasons to prefer a thing to an alternative. How do you expect this question to have a single specific answer. Questions with many equally valid answers are inappropriate to ask on this site.

Comment: I really would love to know at least one valid answer to my question. What would be these myriad of reasons to make the amount of people move away of planet in a sustentable way by like 130 continuous years, @sphennings? Even the colonization of America dont move something comparable.

Comment: @RodolfoPenteado Look at how many different reasons people chose to travel to the Americas. You have people seeking adventure, or a sea route to India, you had exploring this newly "discovered" land, and behind each of those goals you could choose to write whatever character motivation you want. It will be the same for space. Perhaps someone is seeking to escape from the memories of a failed relationship. Perhaps someone is following a girl. Perhaps someone is pursuing economic opportunity. Perhaps someone is seeking to escape persecution. Literally any character motivation is a valid answer.

Comment: none of these reasons or even the sum of them all is a strong socio-economic force to create the need I describe. Need something still stronger than just adventures, fashion, fun at low gravity. These ones are part of question introdution when I mentioned about wealthy resorts of ideology driven groups.

Comment: Why do muslims visit the Vallis Marinellis?

Comment: @Daron added the answer in the question last annex.

Comment: Because they were born there and as a result of growing up in orbit are simply physiologically incapable of living in the full gravity of earth 

Comment: Iain Bank's *Culture* are so detached from planets that *all* humans live in space or on rings. This is because they have some powerful belief that they shouldn't sully natural planets. I don't buy in, but I passed it off as believable when I read the books.

Comment: This post is way too long, with too much extraneous information.

Comment: Why would 1/5th of humanity prefer to not live on Earth specifically, or on any planet's surface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No Law in Space**

Many people are bored and frustrated with their utopian life on Earth. Rightly or wrongly, they want to go back to the bad old days of free market capitalism.

These people were causing a fuss. Since proselytism is illegal there is no way to convince them of the horrors of capitalism. The only option was to show them. The compromise was made to allow these people to set up their own capitalist state on the now empty orbital ring.

Of course, in line with the New Declaration, free passage is allowed to and from the ring at any moment. People can opt in and out of the capitalism if they change their mind.

Answer (score 7):

**Low gravity feels good**

[image: iz floating]

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alone_in_IZ_World)

Because in this bucolic future world the eating is good.  And people don't smoke because ew.  No diseases so people get old and the older they get, the bigger they get.

It is nice to float when you are that big.  Pressure is off the joints and the backside.  You can take a breath.  You don't feel the Earth trying to pull you underground every second.   Low grav environments are merciful to large folk and so that is where they go.  And there get larger.  It is OK!  In this future world people don't judge.

Comment: Well, those born on Mars will grow up in an environment with 1/3 of Earth's gravity, but Earthlings who live there will be able to take advantage of this. Later stations that emulate the gravity of Mars will look like this, however most of them will still be Earth like in their living areas. Now, some fun like space tourism or vomit comet? This was my previous question 2 years ago:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/176088/artistic-performance-in-low-gravity

Answer (score 7):

**It's fashionable.**

*Live on earth? With all the dirt? And the....moo-skee-toes? Ugh. Sounds wretched. You know, I hear sometimes water just falls from the sky! Like you could be out shopping and now you're wet! I heard Nancy has a cousin who lives there. How embarrassing for her!*

As I reckon, humans do all kinds of things out of a sense of fashion, and we do it by the millions. Really just go cruise through google images for "fashion of the [insert decade here]" and wonder why people did any of that. Why were hats in style? Fashion. Why did they go out of style? Fashion. What's with the powdered wigs? Fashion. Why did sun glasses get huge? Fashion. (Typically, these things had some real roots. What you really need are some really popular people to start doing something and now everyone wants to do it.)

So I think if getting into space is generally affordable for a fifth of the population, and if that's where a lot of the high profile celebrities and pop artists are living, then you can start a snowball effect as people who want to be fashionable join the craze, which causes more people to join the craze, and next thing you know everyone wants to do it, *even if it doesn't really make any sense.*

Possibly just the developers had some really good commercials. Probably hired that same team that did the Old Spice commercials... *(Look at your house, now back to me. Look down. Look up. Where are you. You're on a space station, with the man your man could be like.)*

Also I think this explanation gives you a nice story leverage point if you ever need it: fashion can change quickly.

Comment: Its a pretty good answer. Fashion can make some pontual booms of migration to stations, but is not sustentable as trend to like 130 years, and expect still more 60 years.

Comment: @RodolfoPenteado - Kinda thinking about the automobile in America. Not sure how much of it is attributable to "fashion" but for whatever reason, they designed their entire country around the automobile. Now it's hard to get rid of them. A trend can sometimes become so solidified that you're stuck with it. Once people trended onto stations, they may be more or less stuck there, as there aren't good paying jobs, infrastructure, or for-sale property to move back down to, even if it becomes uncool later. Just a thought, anyway!

Comment: One generation may be stuck, two perhaps, but not 3 or more unless these new situation brings a situation lock them. As example: mars children will grow bigger than earth people, in 3 generations they will be 60% tall and take several differences to earthlings, make to they impossible set foot on Earth like a earthling never will support to live in Jupiter. The depopulation problem of earth cities is one actual force against people stabilish in stations, so, need something strong to fix so many in orbit. Not only to make people want, but make politicians allow it.

Answer (score 3):

### It's where the work is.

Even in the Utopian world, people still want to do things. The orbital is a huge research and material processing complex, that needs people monitoring the drones that grab asteroids, researching strange findings, and experimenting.

Of course, despite the presence of treatments for the loss of bone density and so forth, coming down after being there for several months is painful, akin to rehab from a major physical injury. So, most workers on the ring live there pretty permanently, and many even have families living there. There's no real shortage of space (you just bolt on another living pod) and it's seen by people as a way of having less impact on the planet below.

Comment: Habitable domes of stations provide an artificial gravity of 9.81 m/s² like Earth. There no gravity issues related.

Comment: @RodolfoPenteado - I think prehaps then I'd propose that the ring environment is pretty disease free - so people leaving the ring get pretty sick. Basically trying to avoid the ring ending up like an oil rig, where people come for multi month shifts without a family, but instead have an incentive to not make the journey down too much

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Not exactly "no law" but the chance of live one non-urban life without the weight of all engessed surface laws under their heads.

Two generations after the end of great depression (2050) and the stablishment of city-estates these are a bit decadent. The new generation borned in 2070 ~ 2090 looks like the G.I. gen and gen Z (artist) rather the nomad (like gen X) generation of city-state founders. Artist archetip generations are more colectives and feel depressed in the big anonym of the big cities. In Earth, even live in Angra do Heroísmo in middle of north Atlantic ocean make you associate to society of Lisbon in their civic demands and rituals.

This is different in the stations: in Phoenix West 4,323 "Naha" they arent asked about the referendums of the neighbour Phoenix West 4,264 "Akita". They apply the old town meeting to discuss if will hire a new gardening teacher or start a class of yoga. In the past meeting they closed the low gravity orchidarium after a fungi contamination. Once a year, are questioned to affiliate in one federation of stations. Like the majority of stations the choose is no. Choose the deputies to represent the whole Clarke ring in the Parliament in New York is enough.

Of course, they will have childrens went be more individualistic (like baby boomers and gen X) and all those meetings to discuss obvious bored things tire their souls. Nothing happens there! And, look this whole blue planet under us! (Station Naha sit 35789 km above equador line at 174.7º west, near Baker Island, from this point can barely see Australia, New Guinea, New Zealand and Japan). Bachelor in oceanography and can explore the sea? Lets go! Darwin, Cingapore and Durban has the best courses!

Althoug, time pass, another generation more colectivist comes. The lifestyle chilling, drinking tea and learning bonsai, or just lay in a brazilian hammock enjoying Bowie singing Starman is attrative again.

The answer was everytime in my face: generation transition like Strauss Howe theory. Different legislation to orbit and surface is able to make the desire of one whole generation move on.

Thanks, Daron and JamieB, your answers bring nice insights. Willk, I still read this site because your answers around. Miss Renan and Adrian Colomitchi.

Sadly, all these comments of lazy answers claim "opinion based, close the question" each time more common in the forum block creativity and interaction. Enough of Worldbuilding to me.